# How to declare a QPoint(x,y)

Tags: c++, qt5

Sorry to ask this question, but I have a `QPoint` that should carry x coordinate and y coordinate like this `QPoint(x, y)` and I am not sure how to declare it.

I have looked on the QT official documentation for the `QPoint` but I think I am missing something.

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(); 
    Item(const QString &name = "", const QPoint &coordinateXY = QPoint());

    QString name() const { return mName; }
    QPoint mAXY() const { return mAXY(); }

private:
    QString mName;
    QPoint mAXY();
};
#endif // ITEM_H


#include "item.h"
Item::Item(const QString &name, const QPoint &coordinateXY):
    mName(name),
    mAXY(aCoor);
{     }
```

I would like to declare a `QPoint` that carries both x and y coordinates and I am not sure if I should declare N.2 `QPoint` or if I should declare both x and y on the same `QPoint`.

Thanks so much for your support!

Comment: change `mAXY()` to `mAXY` and `QPoint mAXY() const {...` to `QPoint AXY() const { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have declared a variable

```
QPoint mAXY;
```

then you can GET the point doing

```
QPoint mAXY() const { return mAXY; }
```

note the `return mAXY;` instead of `return mAXY();` which will cause a recursive calling of the function maybe crashing the app since an overflow in the stak may happen.

as a rule of code, you could name the getter using the prefix *get*

like

```
QPoint getmAXY() const { return mAXY; }
```

Comment: That is what I was missing! Thanks for the answer, that was very useful!